# How do I add Form Text in Email Body ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html-email

In the past I have used something like this to send form fields in an E-mail form asp.net, I am trying to format more the html email but I dont know how to pass the textbox value into the message can someone help me?

```
//OLD WAY
message.Body += "<b>Preferred contact method: </b> " + drp_contact_method.SelectedValue + "<br/>";//


protected void btnAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Page.IsValid))
        {
            if (dpAction.SelectedValue.ToString()=="Submit" )
            {
            // define SMTP client

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("IP HERE");
            //smtp.EnableSsl = true; 
            // smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            //create the mail message
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

            //From address will be given as a MailAddress Object
            message.From = new MailAddress("myemail@domain.com");


            //To address collection of MailAddress
            message.To.Add("ric.gutierrez@domain.com");
            message.Subject = "Pre-Registration Form";


            // Change to false to not include HTML 

            string bodyHTML = string.Empty;
            string bodyPlain = string.Empty;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            bodyHTML = @"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN'
'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table style='width:800px; border:1px solid #000;' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0' align='center'>
<tr>
<td colspan='2' style='background-color:#009797; border-bottom:1px solid #000;'>
<h1 style='text-align:center; color:#FFF;'>Pre-Registration Information</h1></td>
</tr>
  <td style='width:600px; vertical-align:top;'>
<h4 style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000;'><u>PATIENT INFORMATION</u></h4>
<p style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:.8em; color:#000; line-height:1.5em;'>Last Name:</p>
+ txtLastName.Text +
```

Comment: Typically you don't write out your html in the class file like this, you create a user control and put the business logic within the user controls code behind. Then in your email sending class/method you can execute the user control in the same way it would get executed by throwing the control on a page, except you can just get back the html string that it would end up sending to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cleanest way to do this is to use `string.Format`.  First define your HTML as you currently have in `bodyHTML`, but put placeholders like `{0}` and `{1}` in the string.  Then, plug in your form variables like this:

```
var body = string.Format(
    bodyHTML, 
    HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(yourTextBox.Text), 
    HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(yourOtherTextBox.Text));
```

That will substitute `{0}` with `yourTextBox.Text` and `{1}` with `yourOtherTextBox.Text`, with both values encoded properly for the HTML.

Comment: I have several variables , around 20, would that hold all of them? can you show me what exactly need to change on my code

Comment: Your format string could contain as many placeholders as you'd like, so this technique should work.